# Loading CSS using Webpack and React

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am building an app which uses client-server comunications and server-google cloud platform comunications by using socket.io. For the front-end part I'm using React where I have two components App and Touch. In the future I'll change project structures but rigth now it looks like this

My project structure is the following one:

```
nodemodulesFolder
publicFolder
  jsFolder
     client.js
     socket.io.js
     socket.io.js
     socket.io.js.map
     touch.js
  viewFolder
     App.js
     index.css
     Touch.js
  index.js
  routes.js
.dockerignore
.env
.gitignore
deployment.yaml
Dockerfile
index.js
ingress.yaml
Jenkinsfike
package.json
package-lock.json
server.js
webpack.config.js
```

My CSS file looks like this:

```
body { 
    font-family: sans-serif;
}



p {
    color: black;
}

a {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2a2a2a;
}

a:visited {
    font-weight: normal;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}


.wrapper {
    width: 90vw;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 160px;
}

.greyText {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.buttonWrapper{
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 140px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #ddd;
}

#ResultText {
    width: 80vw;
    margin-bottom: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#ResultText span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#sessionSpeechData {
    width: 80vw;
}

#sessionSpeechData span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.nl-Adjective {
    background-color: #1ada47;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.nl-Noun {
    background-color: #151ffa;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
}

.nl-Verb {
    background-color: #ff1616;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


.hiddenForms {
    opacity: 0.2;
}

h1 {
    color: black;
} 


/* ==========================================================================
   Media Queries
   ========================================================================== */

/*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/*Above */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {} 

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {}

@media print, (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min-resolution: 120dpi) {}

/* ==========================================================================
   Helper classes
   ========================================================================== */

.hidden {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.visuallyhidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

.visuallyhidden.focusable:active, .visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
}

.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Print styles
   ========================================================================== */

@media print {
    *, *:before, *:after {
        background: transparent !important;
        color: #000 !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }
    a, a:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    a[href]:after {
        content: " (" attr(href) ")";
    }
    abbr[title]:after {
        content: " (" attr(title) ")";
    }
    a[href^="#"]:after, a[href^="javascript:"]:after {
        content: "";
    }
    pre, blockquote {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
    thead {
        display: table-header-group;
    }
    tr, img {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }
    p, h2, h3 {
        orphans: 3;
        widows: 3;
    }
    h2, h3 {
        page-break-after: avoid;
    }
}


.btn {
    background-color: #4285f4;
    color: #fff;
    width:140px;
    height:100px;
  }

  .btn:hover {
    background-color: #296CDB;
  }

  .btn:focus {
    background-color: #0F52C1;
    outline: 0;
  }

  .btn:active {
    background-color: #0039A8;
  }


  #startRecButton {
      background-color: #1ada47;
      margin-right:80px; 
  }


  #startRecButton:hover {
    background-color: #1ada47;
  }

  #startRecButton:focus {
    background-color: rgb(62, 180, 38);
    outline: 0;
  }

  #startRecButton:active {
    background-color: rgb(64, 114, 44);
  }
```

But I get the following error in the compiling time:

```
/Users/raulvilloravalencia/OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Madrid/Documents/cp-test-app-2/cp-test-app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:558
      throw err;
      ^

SyntaxError: /Users/raulvilloravalencia/OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Madrid/Documents/cp-test-app-2/cp-test-app/public/views/index.css: Unexpected token, expected ; (1:5)
> 1 | body {
    |      ^
  2 |     font-family: sans-serif;
  3 | }
  4 |
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (/Users/raulvilloravalencia/OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Madrid/Documents/cp-test-app-2/cp-test-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/raulvilloravalencia/OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Madrid/Documents/cp-test-app-2/cp-test-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/Users/raulvilloravalencia/OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Madrid/Documents/cp-test-app-2/cp-test-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1742:38)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/raulvilloravalencia/OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Madrid/Documents/cp-test-app-2/cp-test-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2236:8)
    at Parser.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/raulvilloravalencia/OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Madrid/Documents/cp-test-app-2/cp-test-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:5934:20)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/raulvilloravalencia/OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Madrid/Documents/cp-test-app-2/cp-test-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1911:17)
    at Parser.parseStatement (/Users/raulvilloravalencia/OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Madrid/Documents/cp-test-app-2/cp-test-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:5910:22)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlockBody (/Users/raulvilloravalencia/OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Madrid/Documents/cp-test-app-2/cp-test-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2268:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/raulvilloravalencia/OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Madrid/Documents/cp-test-app-2/cp-test-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1778:8)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/raulvilloravalencia/OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Madrid/Documents/cp-test-app-2/cp-test-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1673:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `webpack && node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/raulvilloravalencia/.npm/_logs/2018-09-28T10_17_39_236Z-debug.log
```

My webpack.config.js file is the following:

```
'use strict'

module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + '/public/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      },
      { test: /\.css$/,
        use:[ {loader: 'css-loader'} ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi Joe, could you please post the contents of your `webpack.config.js` file?

Answer (score 3):

You also need style-loader

Install style-loader first

```
npm install style-loader --save-dev
```

Webpack 3 version

```
  { test: /\.css$/,
    use:[ {loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'} ]
  }
```

webpack 4 version

```
  {
     test: /\.css$/,
     loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
  }
```

Comment: After installing style-loader and changing the webpack with the code you provide, do I need to change the components?

Comment: That's what I think I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you restarted your react app after adding the config?

Comment: Yes, I've started again.

Answer (score 0):

Show content of webpack.config.js. It seems you're missing css/style loaders. [THIS](https://javascriptplayground.com/css-modules-webpack-react/) should help you set it up properly.

```
{
   module: {
     rules: [
       {
         test: /\.css$/,
         use: [
           { loader: "style-loader" },
           { loader: "css-loader" }
         ]
       }
    ]
  }
}
```